# Creating Multiple Criteria Search in Access on Multiple Tables

Tags: excel, ms-access

I have 3 tables in Access that are linked to 3 Excel spread sheets. Each sheet has the same fields and naming conventions. I would like to find a simple way to conduct a union query. My current code is:

```
SELECT [13F].Rank, [13F].[Account Name], [13F].[Fund/Contact], [13F].Symbol, [13F].Type, [13F].Shares, [13F].Date, [13F].Source
FROM 13F
WHERE Symbol = "AAPL" Or Symbol = "AAP"
UNION ALL
SELECT Emails.Rank, Emails.[Account Name], Emails.[Fund/Contact], Emails.Symbol, Emails.Type, Emails.Shares, Emails.Date, Emails.Source
FROM Emails
WHERE Symbol = "AAPL" Or Symbol = "AAP"
UNION ALL SELECT Trade_Blotter.Rank, Trade_Blotter.[Account Name],    Trade_Blotter.[Fund/Contact], Trade_Blotter.Symbol, Trade_Blotter.Type, Trade_Blotter.Shares, Trade_Blotter.Date, Trade_Blotter.Source
FROM Trade_Blotter
WHERE Symbol = "AAPL" Or Symbol = "AAP"
ORDER BY Rank, [Account Name];
```

The "WHERE Symbol =" can become pretty lengthy. Often I am searching over 10-15 variables. I am unfamiliar with SQL so perhaps this is much easier than I am making it but what I would like to do is create a variable that I could use for this WHERE statement. For instance,

```
**Tickers** = "AAPL" Or "AAP" Or "GOOG" Or "CSC"
SELECT [13F].Rank, [13F].[Account Name], [13F].[Fund/Contact], [13F].Symbol, [13F].Type, [13F].Shares, [13F].Date, [13F].Source
FROM 13F
WHERE Symbol = **Tickers**
```

I know this isnt the normal syntax for SQL but hopefully you get my drift. I am trying to prevent having to retype what I want 3 times or accidentally copying and pasting over code.

Thanks

Comment: My inclination would be to do this in  2 steps - first, a union query with no "where" clause.  Then I would make a table with one row for each of the ticker symbols I cared about, and write a 2nd query that joins the union query to the table and returns the results of the union only for the symbols in the symbol table.

Comment: just write one query in access that does the union.  then use it as the source for your query to apply where clauses to.

Comment: And also there is the `IN` clause you can use in `WHERE` statements: `WHERE Symbol IN ("AAPL", "AAP", "GOOG", "CSC")`